# Curl command with options in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In `requests` library, if you need to execute

```
curl http://www.example.com/file.xlsx
```

The command is

```
response = requests.get('http://www.example.com/file.xlsx')
```

What If I want to execute the command with `-O` option?

```
curl http://www.example.com/file.xlsx -O
```

How do I achieve that?

Comment: it is not clear whether you need the curl command with `O` option or the requests equivalent of curl command

Comment: I want to achieve `curl http://www.example.com/file.xlsx -O` using python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no explicit "-O" = write to the same filename.
You if you need that, you can store the url in a variable
and use several ways of getting it. A lazy way is using `rpartition('/')[2]` on
the url string.

The rest of the code to quickly save the result is here:

```
import requests
from pathlib import Path

response = requests.get('http://www.example.com/file.xlsx')
Path('file.xlsx').write_bytes(response.content)

# or if you want to have the file name extracted use this less readable line
# Path(response.url.rpartition('/')[2]).write_bytes(response.content)
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve the use case of CURL's -O option in Python, you have to write few lines of code like,

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://your.url.com/path')

with open('path.txt','w') as fd:
    fd.write(r.text)
```

Comment: Your example only works for text files. To write a binary file (like from the question), you need to open the file with "wb" and write `r.content` instead of the `r.text`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure `requests` supports a flag for this purpose. However, you can try doing something like:

```py
from pathlib import Path

p = Path('http://www.example.com/file.xlsx')
r = requests.get(str(p))
Path(p.name).write_bytes(r.content)
```